# How do I send data between two programs in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, flask, pipe

I have a program "A" written in Python that traps HTTP Requests/Responses going from my browser to the internet and back. I want to display those HTTP Requests/Responses on a web app (program "B") I'm building using Flask.

What is the best way to 'send' the captured data from program 'A' to 'B'

Right now, I'm creating two pipes from program "B" and instantiating the main object in program "A", once I have data to display...program "A" writes it out to a pipe and program "B" reads/displays it.

This does not seem to be working consistently and I'm seeing data encoding issues as well.
Before investing additional time on this approach, I wanted to get your thoughts on this.

Is this the best way to communicate between program 'A' and 'B'? or are there others?

Comment: There's no one "best" way here. Pipes should work as well as anything else. Just remember that neither pipes, nor sockets, know anything about the structure of the bytes you are sending and receiving, so you have to have some sort of "application-level protocol" between the parties.

Comment: You can also use a UNIX socket. You can also develop a simple protocol that includes a header with a length field.

Comment: Please share some code for us to give you a better answer if possible

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: Thanks for the comment. I'm moving forward using pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database layer in between.

We faced the same issue and we resolved it by sending HTTP requests to Redis instance and another application reading it. we wanted to monitor the HTTP requests.

This way you can achieve persistence of data also.